# Want to point a domain to a host and already changed nameservers, what's next?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, cpanel, nameserver

To be totally honest this is driving me mad because I know it's probably something simple.

So I have my domain (elogee.com) registered at 1and1.com while my host is GoDaddy. Right, every article I've read says I should write the GoDaddy name servers (ns23.domaincontrol.com and ns24.domaincontrol.com) on the domain website and that should do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work. The problem is that every article stops there and implies that the work is done. Some people said I need to add elogee.com to my addon domain on cPanel but that doesn't work because I have a limit of zero addons (probably because of my plan). Also, the domains section on my cPanel says elogee.com is my primary domain, which is strange because when I look up the website I don't get anything. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the names of the Godaddy Nameservers to use?   Godaddy should specify the servers somewhere in your account.  If you used ones that you found somewhere else on the internet, they could be ones that Godaddy uses for somebody else's account and which won't work for your account.

Comment: It looks like maybe your nameserver changes didn't get made or didn't go through yet.  If I run the command  `dig NS elogee.com` I see four nameservers listed:  `ns1095.ui-dns.com.`, `ns1043.ui-dns.de.`, `ns1119.ui-dns.org.`, and `ns1057.ui-dns.biz.`   How long ago did you change the NS records?  Did you change them at your domain registrar?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - wtf?  When I looked in intodns yesterday the nameservers were pointing to domaincontrol.com :P

Comment: I thought you said you're registrar is one and one.  That is where you need to make name server changes. I'm not sure how into DNS is even figuring into this.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller intodns.com is simply a DNS reporting tool.  have a look at https://intodns.com/stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting only allows 1 website and that site is not your domain, then you need to either upgrade so you can include the new domain as an `addon` or you need a separate hosting plan.  Looking at the DNS settings at [intoDNS](https://intodns.com/elogee.com) it can be seen that the nameservers are pointing to godaddy.  Visiting your domain it takes me to `http://elogee.com/defaultsite` which to me indicates that the domain is in godaddy DNS but it isn't configured properly.

Have you tried calling godaddy technical support?